# Zero indexed array in Fortran?

Tags: fortran, fortran90

Can someone explain what is **zero indexed array in Fortran** along with example. I'm not getting any content on that on internet.

Comment: If I enter that bold-faced phrase into a popular search engine's input box the second hit returned answers this question.  It beggars belief that you too can't find similar material.

Comment: 1. This question is answered in any introductory material in Fortran. 2. You are not asking a question.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark insulting others never benefits anyone. I was posting question on after a very long period of time that's why I thought to be polite and because of this behaviour from users I left.

Comment: The question here and the presented duplicate are not equivalent. Related, at best. The question is also not answered in the duplicate post.

Comment: @PrashantShukla However, HighPerformanceMark was not really insulting anyone, he was directly replying to your claim *"I'm not getting any content on that on internet."* that is impossible to believe.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

A *zero indexed array* is an array who's index origin is `ZERO`. This means that the first element of the array is referenced by index `0`.

Fortran arrays defaultly start with index 1 when you declare them

```
INTEGER, DIMENSION(3) :: v
```

Here, the symbol `v` represents a one-dimensional array of size 3 with elements `v(1)`,`v(2)` and `v(3)`.

However, the [Fortran standard](http://www.j3-fortran.org/doc/year/10/10-007.pdf) gives you the possibility to set the starting and ending index of your array. E.g.:

```
INTEGER, DIMENSION(0:2) :: w
```

In this case, the symbol `w` represents again a one-dimensional array of size `3`. But now with elements `w(0)`,`w(1)` and `w(2)`. As the starting index is `0` this is a *zero indexed array*.

For an explicit shape array [Section 5.3.8.2 of the standard](http://www.j3-fortran.org/doc/year/10/10-007.pdf) states that the `DIMENSION` attribute can be declared as

```
DIMENSION ( [lower-bound :] upper-bound )
```

So anything is possible, you can start with `-42` and end with `+42` if you want.

> The values of each `lower-bound` and `upper-bound` determine the bounds of
>   the array along a particular dimension and hence the extent of the
>   array in that dimension. If `lower-bound` appears it specifies the lower bound; otherwise the lower bound is 1. The value of a lower bound or an upper bound may be positive, negative, or zero. The subscript range of the array in that dimension is the set of integer values between and including the lower and upper bounds, provided the upper bound is not less than the lower bound. If the upper bound is
>   less than the lower bound, the range is empty, the extent in that
>   dimension is zero, and the array is of zero size.