# Fortan suggestions needed on array values

Tags: arrays, fortran, gfortran

I'm new to fortran and need some resources where I can start learning the basics. This problem might be very trivial but, currently, I have a code which was written in probably the older version, and is showing a warning message which reads:

```
gfortran -O2 -ffpe-summary='none' -c argo.f
argo.f:2060:37:

 2051 |       DO J=0,THRESHOLD
      |                                                                        2
......
 2060 |         MUAVNEW = MUAVNEW + MASSJ*SN(J)
      |                                     1
Warning: Array reference at (1) out of bounds (0 < 1) in loop beginning at (2)
argo.f:2061:29:

 2051 |       DO J=0,THRESHOLD
      |                                                                        2
......
 2061 |         DENTOT = DENTOT + SN(J)
      |                             1
Warning: Array reference at (1) out of bounds (0 < 1) in loop beginning at (2)
```

Could you advise on how to avoid this warning?

Comment: By default, unless defined differently in the array declaration, indices of arrays start counting from 1 and not from zero.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Zero indexed array in Fortran?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48562873/zero-indexed-array-in-fortran)

Comment: Thank you. I'm not sure if I did it correctly, but changing a value from 0 to 1 removed the warning messages. If possible, also let me know some sources to get started with Fortran.