# Problem with arrays: removing repeated elements from an array in Fortran

Tags: arrays, indexing, fortran

I have an array A with repeated elements and my objective is to create a new one B that returns the same data as in A, but with no repetitions.

When I execute the following code, I get the desired results by printing arrays A and B. However, when I print the first element of B (B(1)), the result is incorrect. Could you please help?

```
program unique

  implicit none
   double precision, dimension(24)             :: A = (/0.0d0,0.0d0,0.0d0,0.0d0,&
       0.2d0,0.2d0,0.2d0,0.2d0,&
       0.4d0,0.4d0,0.4d0,0.4d0,&
       0.59d0,0.59d0,0.59d0,0.59d0,&
       0.8d0,0.8d0,0.8d0,0.8d0,&
       0.1d1,0.1d1,0.1d1,0.1d1/)  
  double precision, dimension(:), allocatable :: B

  call unique_sub(A,B)

  print*, 'B    =', B
  print*, 'A(1) = ', A(1)
  print*, 'B(1) =', B(1)
  print*, 'size(B)', size(B)

contains

  subroutine unique_sub(A_nonUnique,A_Unique)

    implicit none
    double precision, dimension(:), intent(in)               :: A_nonUnique  
    double precision, dimension(:), allocatable, intent(out) :: A_Unique
    logical, dimension(:), allocatable                       :: mask
    integer, dimension(:), allocatable                       :: index_vector
    integer                                                  :: i, n

    n = size(A_nonUnique)

    ! First, find the duplicate elements
    allocate(mask(n))
    mask = .true.

    do i = n,2,-1
       mask(i) = .not.(any(A_nonUnique(i)==A_nonUnique(:i-1))) ! if element A_nonUnique(i) appears in A_nonUnique(1:i-1) false, otherwise it is a unique element
    end do

    ! Make an index vector
    allocate(index_vector, source=pack([(i, i=1,n) ],mask))
    ! Now copy the unique elements of a into A_Unique
    allocate(A_Unique, source=A_nonUnique(index_vector))

    print*, 'mask', mask
    print*, 'index_vector = ', index_vector    
    print*, 'A_nonUnique(index_vector) =', A_nonUnique(index_vector)
    print*, 'A_Unique                  =', A_Unique
    print*, 'A_nonUnique(1) =', A_nonUnique(1)
    print*, 'A_Unique(1)    =', A_Unique(1)

  end subroutine unique_sub

end program unique
```

printed results are:

```
 mask T F F F T F F F T F F F T F F F T F F F T F F F
 index_vector =            1           5           9          13          17          21
 A_nonUnique(index_vector) =   0.0000000000000000       0.20000000000000001       0.40000000000000002       0.58999999999999997       0.80000000000000004        1.0000000000000000     
 A_Unique                  =   0.0000000000000000       0.20000000000000001       0.40000000000000002       0.58999999999999997       0.80000000000000004        1.0000000000000000     
 A_nonUnique(1) =   0.0000000000000000     
 A_Unique(1)    =  0.20000000000000001     
 B    =   0.0000000000000000       0.20000000000000001       0.40000000000000002       0.58999999999999997       0.80000000000000004        1.0000000000000000     
 A(1) =    0.0000000000000000     
 B(1) =  0.20000000000000001     
 size(B)           6
```

Comment: Which compiler are you using? It does that with gfortran (which seems to end up with a lower bound of 0), but doesn't do it with the NAG compiler (which behaves as expected).

Comment: I use gfortran.

Comment: Mmm, gfortran does indeed produce that output, but neither NAG nor Intel compilers do. gfortran seems to produce an array with bounds running from 0 to 5, rather than 1 to 6. Try printing lbound(B) and ubound(B).

Comment: Wow, I did not know that the indexing can start from 0 in fortran. Did I do something wrong with allocation? When I modify the code to print A(0) and A_nonUnique(0), I have a warning: Array reference at (1) is out of bounds (0 < 1) in dimension 1. But this does not happen when I print B(0) or A_unique(0). I am puzzled.

Comment: Yes, I'm puzzled too. I don't see anything wrong with your allocation. I think gfortran may have a bug with the source= bit in the allocation statement, because the other compilers are OK. If your replace the allocation of A_Unique with the separate statements ```allocate(A_Unique(count(mask)));   A_Unique=A_nonUnique(index_vector)``` then all is fine.

Comment: Here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48562873/zero-indexed-array-in-fortran, it has been explained that 0 indexing is possible. But the example shows that this can be done if something like INTEGER, DIMENSION(0:2) :: w is specified instead of INTEGER, DIMENSION(3) :: v. Which is not the case in my example.

Comment: No, I think the behaviour of gfortran is wrong here, but there are people on the forum with much better experience than I, so I should sit it out and see.

Comment: By adding what you suggested and printing the following:                                                                 print*, 'A_nonUnique(0) =', A_nonUnique(index_vector(0))
    print*, 'A_Unique(0)    =', A_Unique(0)
    print*, 'A_nonUnique(1) =', A_nonUnique(index_vector(1))
    print*, 'A_Unique(1)    =', A_Unique(1)
    print*, 'A_nonUnique(2) =', A_nonUnique(index_vector(2))
    print*, 'A_Unique(2)    =', A_Unique(2)

Comment: I have                                                                                                                                               A_nonUnique(0) =   0.0000000000000000     
 A_Unique(0)    =   3.2114266979681025E-322
 A_nonUnique(1) =  0.20000000000000001     
 A_Unique(1)    =   0.0000000000000000     
 A_nonUnique(2) =  0.40000000000000002     
 A_Unique(2)    =  0.20000000000000001

Comment: which is more puzzling. Because this time, I don't have any warning and bounds  of A_nonUnique are shifted.

Comment: The lower bound of `B` should indeed be `1`: that is the lower bound in the source expression when the argument associated `A_Unique` is allocated.

Comment: What version of gfortran?

Comment: OK, I remembered this bug from older versions of gfortran and thought it had been fixed, but it's more complex than that. On my machine it gives incorrect values for B(1) for gfortran versions 7.5 and 8.4, but works for 9.4, 10.3 and 11.1. However it fails again for 12.2, so it looks as though a regression test is needed for this case. I would submit this program as part of a bug report for gfortran.

Comment: As regards bounds in Fortran one of its strengths is you can choose the array bounds to be what you want. However the default being 1 does have some implications, especially in expressions involving arrays.

Comment: Yes, the bug has been around before: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=88710  and https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=89925 . I concur with @Ian Bush: it looks like it has reappeared.

Comment: I am using gfortran 7.5.